# Как получить ключ GPG?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpg

Хочу установить и опробовать `docker`. В инструкции по установке есть такой пункт:

> Add the new GPG key.

Погуглил и оказалось, что такой криптографисеский ключ. Но как его сгенирировать на `Ubuntu` я не нашел. Не подскажите ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Его не нужно генерировать вообще.

Это публичный ключ, которым подписываются пакеты Docker, чтобы пользователи могли быть уверены в том, что пакет пришёл от команды Docker. Описанная там команда запуска `apt-key` (длинная такая, с большим блоком буквоцифр в конце) полностью выполняет процедуру добавления и содержит "отпечаток" (тот самый блок буквоцифр), по которому она может убедиться, что это именно тот ключ, который имелся в виду на сайте.

---

Можно ли верить команде, изложенной в этой инструкции и считать, что это правильный ключ? Ну, если вы просматриваете страницу по HTTPS и не получаете предупреждений о неверном сертификате, то да. *При условии, конечно, что вам в хранилище корневых сертификатов не добавили ничего сомнительного. Вы сами или кто-то ещё, вроде вашего системного администратора.*